# Linq to objects aggregated optional fields

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-objects

Given a list of purchase orders, some of them partially shipped, some of them fully shipped, I'm struggling to write a linq to objects query that groups the orders by month and summarizes the amounts ordered and the amounts shipped.

```
Public Class Order
Property OrderDate as Date
Property Items as List(Of OrderItem)
end Class

Public Class OrderItem
Property Sku as string
Property Qty as integer
Property Price as decimal
Property Shipments as list(Of Shipments)
End Class

Public Class Shipment
Property ShipmentDate as Date
Property OrderItem as OrderItem
Property ShippedQty as integer
end class

Dim Orders as List(Of Order)=GetOrdersFromSomewhere()
Dim Query=Orders.SelectMany(function(x) x.Items).SelectMany(function(y) y.Shipments)
```

But Query collects only shipped items, skipping those unshipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group orders by month using stringformat "yyyy-MM" for `OrderDate`
Then calculate separately ordered and shipped quantities

```
Dim orders As List(Of Order) = GetOrdersFromSomewhere()
Dim result = orders.GroupBy(Function(o) o.OrderDate.ToString("yyyy-MM")).
                    Select(Function(grp)
                               Return New With
                               {
                                   .Month = grp.Key,
                                   .OrderedSum = grp.Sum(Function(o) o.Items.Sum(Function(item) item.Qty)),
                                   .ShippedSum = grp.Sum(Function(o) o.Items.Sum(Function(item) item.Shipments?.Sum(Function(ship) ship.ShippedQty)))
                               }
                           End Function)

'Print result
For Each month In result
    Console.WriteLine($"{month.Month}{vbTab}Ordered: {month.OrderedSum}, Shipped: {month.ShippedSum}")
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **GroupBy** and then do a **Sum**.

You can add a method to class OrderItem, **TotalPrice** to get the total Price or orders, similarly you can defined a method for getting the AmountShipped price. Here, i demonstrate TotalPrice method for getting the total Price of all the Order.

```
    Public Class OrderItem
    Property Sku as string
    Property Qty as integer
    Property Price as decimal
    Property Shipments as list(Of Shipments)

        Public Function TotalPrice() As Decimal
                    Return CDec(Me.Qty) * Me.Price
                End Function
        End Class
```

Then for grouping the orders by date and getting the sum, you can use following code

```
Dim orders = New GetOrdersFromSomewhere()
Dim ordersGroupedByDate = orders.GroupBy(Function(x) x.OrderDate)

For Each orderByDate As var In ordersGroupedByDate
    Dim dateTimeItem = orderByDate.Key
    Dim sumOfOrderedItems = orderByDate.SelectMany(Function(x) x.Items.[Select](Function(y) y.TotalPrice())).Sum()
Next
```